# sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: - What shall I use now?

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, ios9

What shall I use now instead of `NSURLConnection's`

> sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:

in iOS 9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sendAsynchronousRequest was deprecated in iOS 9. 
     **ObjC**

```
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]
          completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                              NSURLResponse *response,
                              NSError *error) {
            // handle response

  }] ];
```

**Swift**

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    }
```

You have to create a NSMutableURLRequest object and specify your URL and HTTPmethod.

**Note**: You can also create a delegate class and add a NSURLSessionDataDelegate protocol to receive response instead of adding all your network code in UI classes. 
 [tutorial1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-1--mobile-21394) [tutorial2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession)